# dataTable raise error Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, datatable

I have install 3 files:

```
<link href="~/Scripts/DataTables-1.10.0/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/DataTables-1.10.0/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

after that I try to create table:

```
 $('#manage-news').dataTable({ options });
```

but it raise error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I try to debug, I see it go to jquery.dataTables first, run pass this line 14378

```
return $.fn.dataTable;
```

then it goes to my code, selector `$('#manage-news')` has value

```
[<table id=​"manage-news" class=​"display" cellspacing=​"0" width=​"100%" data-view=​"backendModule/​views/​managenews" data-active-view=​"true">​</table>​]
```

I use datatable because it can use ajax datasource, 
please help me to fix this error or show me some javascript table can use ajax datasource.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace dataTable by DataTable :

$('#manage-news').DataTable({ options });